# MVC 3 and "Javascript-Disabled" browsers

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a requirement to implement a web application using MVC 3, which works on browsers even if javascript is disabled. There are a lot of concepts in MVC 3 which rely on the use of jquery.

1. What are the concepts which won't work in the case of "javascript-disabled" browsers?
2. For those concepts which won't work, are there any alternative ways to implement those concepts in MVC 3?
3. With these requirements, is it a good idea to implement such a website using MVC 3, or should it be implemented in asp.net (with every thing done on server side)?

Comment: You will be better implementing your site in MVC than Pure Old ASP.net as you will atleast have full control over the HTML that gets generated in the MVC part..

Comment: I don't recall the last time I heard of someone disabling javascript in their browser. So much of the web relies on it now that you just can't switch it off. And most of the security issues that made people nervous about it have been dealt with over the last few years. Far be it for me to question your requirements, though. ;-)

Comment: I agree with you @Spudley. But while developing an application, one should keep this in mind that the Client is not a technical person. He probably might be very educated and might be leading an organization, yet he might just be knowing this that to open a website he needs to press an icon, enter the address at the top and press enter :-). Not everyone knows about the browser settings. So what if js is disabled in his browser? He won't even realize that the reason why the website is behaving strange is because of some setting in his browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MVC 3 does NOT depend on jQuery to function properly**

The beauty of MVC 3 is that it is pre-packaged with a jQuery plugin which provides unobtrusive form validation. Unobtrusive means that it will work even if Javascript is disabled. MVC 3 does NOT require jQuery nor Javascript to work as intended.

Take a moment to read this blog post. The author does a good job explaining how MVC 3 and jQuery work together.

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 4):

MVC is very nicely set up for doing "progressive enhancement", which is to say getting an app to work first using server-side only and then enhancing with javascript.  There is nothing I can think of in MVC (3 or otherwise) that inherently requires javascript, certainly no more so than ASP.NET WebForms.  And the control that you have over just about every aspect of your application is far greater than in WebForms (at least by default; I am sure you can do anything you want in WebForms if you work hard enough at it).